# How can I turn on the airbag on Mitsubishi Outlander without a key?

Tags: mitsubishi, key, supplemental-restraint-system, fob

In the manual it is written to insert the key for switching. But we have keyless car (just click the start button), and we don't have keys. Is there an alternative way?

I tried using a knife, but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a metal key hidden in your FOB.  The metal tab sticking out the top is the key, press the release button and the key will slide out.

[image: Mitsubishi Key FOB]

Comment: Which is also for when the battery in the fob dies, of course.

Comment: @jwh20. Thank you very much. I was able to turn it on.BTW, How can I use the key if the fob dies. I didn't found any place to start the car only with the key (I can use the key for open the door, but not for start the engin. Is there any hidden place to insert the key in switch to AC like regular key?

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein I am not 100% sure if it is the same but in a Mazda, if you press the fob against the button it will start even if the battery is dead. This is because it completes a circuit similar to the way the modern electric toothbrushes charge when stood on their stand even though there is not visible metal connection.

Comment: @theblitz I believe you right.

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein Check the manual. Somewhere in the car (usually the center console) there is a designated spot where you can place an (empty) fob and it will work. Fobs usually have a NFC chip that can be powered by the fobs battery or by a strong short-distance (typically 4" to 6") radio-signal. The antenna for the radio signal is hidden in the car and the empty fob needs to be very close. It is very similar to the system used by contact-less card-payments seen in many cash-registers these days.

Comment: Yes I have an empty slot. So I believe it will work without battey, and that this is the point of the slot. Thanks!